# How to copy a bunch of files with same name to a folder?

Tags: python, file, directory, copy, shutil

I have some files with different extension.
These files are located in different folders and has same names.
I'd like to copy these files and rename them at the same time.

i have:

- ti.txt
- ti.xlxsx
- ti.pdf

and I would like to rename it to:

- Archive_1.txt
- Archive_2.xlsx
- Archive_3.pdf

**PS: I would have several files of the same type in this new folder**

I researched and found the Shutil library to make the code, but I'm having trouble. Would anyone have any ideas to start with?

**This is what i've tried**

```
# importing os module
import os

# importing shutil module
import shutil

# path
path = r'D:\Usuarios\0025429\Desktop\old_folder'

# List files and directories
# in '/home/User/Documents'
print("Before copying file:")
print(os.listdir(path))

# Source path
source = r"D:\Usuarios\0025429\Desktop\old_folder\IQ.txt"
source = r"D:\Usuarios\0025429\Desktop\old_folder\IQ.xlsx"
source = r"D:\Usuarios\0025429\Desktop\old_folder\IQ.docx"
# Print file permission
# of the source
perm = os.stat(source).st_mode
print("File Permission mode:", perm, "\n")

# Destination path
destination = r"D:\Usuarios\0025429\Desktop\new_folder"

# Copy the content of
# source to destination
dest = shutil.copy(source, destination)
# List files and directories
# in "/home / User / Documents"
print("After copying file:")
print(os.listdir(path))

# Print file permission
# of the destination
perm = os.stat(destination).st_mode
print("File Permission mode:", perm)

# Print path of newly
# created file
print("Destination path:", dest)
```

Comment: Give it a try and mention what you tried here.

Comment: I edited the post with the code I've tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#module-pathlib) to work with filesystem and [`copy()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copy) from `shutil` to copy each file.

```
from shutil import copy
from pathlib import Path

src = Path(r".\dir1")
dst = Path(r".\dir2")
idx = 0
for file in src.iterdir():
    if file.is_file():
        idx += 1
        copy(file, (dst / f"Archive_{idx}").with_suffix(file.suffix))
```

To rename only files with given name use next code:

```
from shutil import copy
from pathlib import Path

src = Path(r".\dir1")
filename = "123"
dst = Path(r".\dir2")
idx = 0
for file in src.iterdir():
    if file.is_file() and file.stem == filename:
        idx += 1
        copy(file, (dst / f"Archive_{idx}").with_suffix(file.suffix))
```

Comment: That's works. Would there be any way for me to select only the files that have the same name? because the folder has 'IQ.txt' (.doc) (. pdf) (. xlsx) and also has files with other names

Comment: @Hendrik, you want to copy only files with same name? I mean 2 or more files with same name but different extensions?

Comment: Yeah, only same name. In other folders i have the same extension and same name with different content.  i want to copy all this files renaming the files, independing it have same or different extension.

Comment: @Hendrik, not clear what to do with renaming. E.g. `1.txt`, `1.jpg` and `1.pdf` will become `Archive_1.txt`, `Archive_2.jpg` and `Archive_3.pdf`, but what if there's also `2.txt` and `2.jpg`? It should be `Archive_4.txt` and `Archive_5.jpg`?

Comment: Would there be some way for me to copy and rename only the files with the name '1.jpg' and not those that are repeated in '2.jpg'